# How to use pixelLonLat() with sampleRectangle() to get a 2-D array of lons and lats

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to convert a clipped ee.Image to 2-D arrays for each band and 2-D arrays for the lats and the lons of each pixel. Some of the pixels could be masked.

Using pixelLonLat() with sampleRectangle() the 2D array is not generated as I expected.

I expected a 2-D array with the latitudes of each pixel. This is the result for the other image bands. But I get a single value, that I don't recognise.

```
// Select a random image and band. 
var bandName= "B1";
var asset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200110T000231_20200110T000234_T55HFB").select(bandName); 
var minMaxReducer = ee.Reducer.minMax();
var theMinMax = asset.reduceRegion(minMaxReducer, asset.geometry());
// print(theMinMax);
var min = theMinMax.get(bandName + '_min').getInfo();
var max = theMinMax.get(bandName + '_max').getInfo();
print('min: ' +  min, ' max: ' +  max)
// create an AOI
var centroid = asset.geometry().centroid(10);
var largeArea = centroid.buffer(100000);
var smallArea = centroid.buffer(15000);

// Add a 'longitude' and 'latitude' band.
var imageWithCoords = asset.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
var smallImage = imageWithCoords.clip(largeArea);
print('smallImage', smallImage);
print('bandNames', smallImage.bandNames());
// Confirm the bands render as exected.
Map.addLayer(smallImage, {"bands":[bandName],"min":min,"max":max}, bandName);
Map.addLayer(smallImage, {"bands":["longitude"],"min":147.676,"max":149.850}, 'longitude');
Map.addLayer(smallImage, {"bands":["latitude"],"min":-35.585,"max":-34.253}, 'latitude');
Map.centerObject(smallImage);

// Get 2-d pixel array for AOI - returns feature with 2-D pixel array as property per band.
var band_arrs = imageWithCoords.unmask(0).sampleRectangle(smallArea)
// Get individual band arrays.
var band_arr = band_arrs.get(bandName);
var band_arr_lats = band_arrs.get('latitude');
var band_arr_lons = band_arrs.get('longitude');

print('bandname', band_arr.getInfo());  // Note the shape is a list of lists (50, 50)
print('lats', band_arr_lats.getInfo()); // Expected the same shape but get (1, 1)
print('lons', band_arr_lons.getInfo()); // Expected the same shape but get (1, 1)
```

The actual output is
lats
[[-34.5]]
lons
[[148.5]]
I am also not sure why the numbers are rounded to half a degree.

An alternative approach is to use reducer.toList() but this gives a 1-D array sampled at a different scale, so not as easy to align with the band arrays.

```
var latlonList = smallImage.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry: smallArea,
    scale: 10
  })

var lats =ee.Array(latlonList.get("latitude")).getInfo();
var lons = ee.Array(latlonList.get("longitude")).getInfo();
print('lats', lats);
print('lons', lons);
```

This prints two lists of 69832 elements each. Depending on the AOI and the scale.

**EDIT**
Adding the image to a pixelLonLat() doesn't work either. i.e.

```
smallImage = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().addBands(smallImage)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs for sampleRectangle:

> Each band is sampled in its input projection

The pixelLonLat image has no projection so it defaults to EPSG:4326 at 1 degree per pixel.  So there's only 1 pixel in your region.  Set the default projection for that image like this:

```
var band_arrs = imageWithCoords.unmask(0)
    .setDefaultProjection(asset.projection())
    .sampleRectangle(smallArea)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed the answer. I was thrown off by the map showing a gradation of lats and lons.